# How can a Kugelblitz form because pair production will occur before that

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, black-holes, pair-production

I might be incorrectly mixing up two separate theories - quantum physics and general relativity but from what I've studied, a Kugelblitz is a black hole that is formed from condensing large amounts of high energy light into a small region of space, enough to cause intense curvature of the spacetime to the extent that an event horizon is formed - a black hole.

However, I've also studied that in particle physics, a high enough energy density in a region of space would give rise to particle-antiparticle pairs, and if that energy is light energy, it would produce electron-positron pairs.

My question is, how can one sustain and continue to add enough energy in a region of space in the attempt to form a kugelblitz but before that the high amounts of energy density leads to particle-antiparticle pairs that escape away from the region? And even if the particles don't escape from the region but contribute to the curvature of spacetime, the resulting black hole isn't a Kugelblitz anymore because it isn't formed from curvature produced solely by light energy.

Comment: isn't kugelblitz a form of lightning consisting of a spherical volume of ionized air?

Comment: @nielsnielsen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)

Comment: @nielsnielsen it literally means *ball lightning* but it's normally taken to mean a concentration of light so intense that it forms a black hole. See [the article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)) for details.

Comment: got it, just read it, thanks for the reference- consider me disambiguated.  -NN

Comment: Why worry about pair production? The particles travel slower than light, so they'll leave the region slower than the photons that you're pumping in do. So they should help the BH to form.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah but in that case, the BH wouldn't be a Kugelblitz - a black hole formed purely from light energy. It would resemble classical black holes that are formed from matter then.

Comment: Just because the light might be converted to matter by pair production would not fundamentally alter the fact that the light created a black hole, even if it created some matter in the process.  So I'd still say the term "Kugelblitz" is valid (and it sounds cool :-) ).

Comment: Once an event horizon was formed (a black hole exists), there is no way to tell from the outside what is inside or what formed it.  This is a result of the [no hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make your black hole very large. The (average) energy density inside a black hole decreases as $1/r_s^2$ so if you make the Schwarzschild radius large enough you can form the black hole without needing EM amplitudes large enough to cause particle production.

Having said this, I don't think anyone is suggesting that you could actually make a kugelblitz. The conditions needed are extreme to a ridiculous extent. The idea is more of a thought experiment. There have been related calculations showing that [a black hole could be made from gravitational waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426233/could-black-holes-be-formed-by-highly-energetic-gravitational-waves), which are also massless radiation. However as with light this would never happen in practice.

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense, kind of like dodging pair production or working around it by decreasing the energy density at a single region of space but the overall energy density remains the same because the increase in volume is compensated by more amount of light energy in the total volume.